# Simple way to add category link in layered navigation so that category open with the actual url insted filter

Tags: magento

I want to add link category link in layered navigation of Magento so that when any visitor click on category in layered navigation it will open with their actual url instead of filtering the results on same page.

I found this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9513/layered-navigation-category-link

but this is little bit confusing. Anyone have any simple way to do this modification?

I know how remove category filter list from layered navigation of each category and now I want to know how can I add any static block above the filters in layered navigation so that I can add subcategory link of every category.

Please give some suggestion.

Comment: what categories do yo want to populate on layered nav ? siblings, subcategories ? or what if you reached end of categories ?

Comment: I want to add subcategories.
In magento subcategories are filter when I do is anchor = yes. So I want subcategories open with their actual link instead of getting result filtered.

Comment: but subcategories appear by default on layered nav, if you look at `catalog/navigation/left.phtml`

Comment: Yes, but when Is Anchor = No that time subcategories open with category url & when Is Anchor = Yes that time products are filter but it does not open with the url, So I want Is Anchor = Yes & subcategories will open with   the category url.

Comment: No Response ? Anyone have any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is using layout handle `<catalog_category_layered />` add a block in left. and on that phtml file using current category get all subcategories.

in your local.xml file

```
<layout>
   <catalog_category_layered>
     <block type="core/template" name="layeredcatnav" template="catalog/navigation/layeredcatnav.phtml"/>
   </catalog_category_layered>
</layout>
```

And inside `catalog/navigation/layeredcatnav.phtml` file

```
  <?php $current_cat = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory();
    $cat_id = $current_cat->getId(); //current category id
    //now get subcategories using this category id
      $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($cat_id);
        foreach ($children as $category) {
            echo $category->getName();
            echo $category->getURL();
        }
 ?>
```

Note : not tested

Comment: Thanks Suman,

I can hide category filters by using below code
<reference name="catalog.leftnav"> 
<action method="unsetChild"><alias>category_filter</alias></action>
</reference>


Now next in step I am thinking to add one block in category > custom design from where I can add subcategories with actual link so that when any user click on that link it will open with url.

So please suggest me if you have any idea about this.

Comment: @Lovely sorry, i couldn't get you.

Comment: Subcategory work as a default categories when is anchor property set to yes

Comment: @Lovely, what you mean `work as a default category` mean ?

Comment: In magento when we set is anchor property Yes the subcategories are converted into filters & also shows other filters like Price, Color & Special price.

I set Is Anchor property Yes in all categories & here I want to do is subcategories will open with default category URL.

I do not make Is anchor property No because I want to show other filters also like price, color & sub categories.

Comment: @Lovely, so for that, above answer solution should give you subcategories even you haven't anchor=yes for a category

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed quite easily by overriding the `getUrl()` method in the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Item class`

```
Go to /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Item.php

public function getUrl()
{
 $query = array(
 $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()=>$this->getValue(),
Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getPageVarName() => null // exclude current page from urls);
return Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true, '_query'=>$query));
}
```

> Change to :

```
public function getUrl()
{
if($this->getFilter()->getRequestVar() == "cat"){
$category_url = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getValue())->getUrl();
 $return = $category_url;
  $request = Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true));
 if(strpos($request,'?') !== false ){
$query_string = substr($request,strpos($request,'?'));
}
else{
 $query_string = '';
}
 if(!empty($query_string)){
 $return .= $query_string;
 }
 return $return;
}
 else{
 $query = array(
 $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()=>$this->getValue(),
Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getPageVarName() => null // exclude current page from urls
 );
return Mage::getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true, '_query'=>$query));
}
}
```

> If It's work for you then please copy Item.php file and put local file on this path  /app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Item.php

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you can you this code for magento 2.

For magento 2, we have the same function in vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item.php we have getUrl() function.

the orignal code:

```
public function getUrl()
    {
        $query = [
            $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar() => $this->getValue(),
            // exclude current page from urls
            $this->_htmlPagerBlock->getPageVarName() => null,
        ];
        return $this->_url->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true, '_query' => $query]);
    }
```

and then the custom code to solve the issue:

```
public function getUrl()
    {
        if($this->getFilter()->getRequestVar() == "cat"){
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $category_url = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($this->getValue())->getUrl();
            $return = $category_url;
            $request = $this->_url->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true));
            if(strpos($request,'?') !== false ){
                $query_string = substr($request,strpos($request,'?'));
            }
            else{
                $query_string = '';
            }
            if(!empty($query_string)){
                $return .= $query_string;
            }
            return $return;
        }
        else{
            $query = array(
                $this->getFilter()->getRequestVar()=>$this->getValue(),
                $this->_htmlPagerBlock->getPageVarName() => null // exclude current page from urls
            );

            return $this->_url->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true, '_query'=>$query));
        }
    }
```

It's working only category section. It's working fine in my case.